# Google Map PolylineOptions() не меняется цвет

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

Я добавляю на карту линию от одной точки к другой.

```
val lines = ArrayList<PolylineOptions>()

for (i in orders2.indices) {
    var line = PolylineOptions()

    if (orders2[i].status != 4) {
        for (j in orders2[i].dots.indices) {
            val lat = orders2[i].dots[j].coordinates.lat
            val lng = orders2[i].dots[j].coordinates.lng
            line.add(LatLng(lat, lng))

        }
    }
    line.color(R.color.colorRed)
    lines.add(line)

}
if(!lines.isNullOrEmpty()){
    for (line in lines) {
        googleMap!!.addPolyline(line)
    }
}
```

Вот если не делать  `line.color(R.color.colorRed)` (любой цвет), то полоса будет черной, иначе, какой-то свой цвет берет.

Как поменять на свой цвет?

Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для начала этот цвет нужно извлечь из ресурсов

```
val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorRed)
line.color(color)
```